# GitHub Pages Custom Domain Settings

Tags: github, dns, github-pages, a-records

I'm trying to configure GitHub with my naked `domain.com` (APEX in GitHub) and `www.domain.com`.

I have `username.github.io` working OK.

My A record is pointing to `192.30.252.153` and `192.30.252.154`.

I then have two CNAME records set:

- `www.domain.com` → `domain.com`
- `io.domain.com` → `username.github.io`

This configuration, however, is not working.

Accessing `domain.com` results in a 404 on GitHub. Meanwhile, accessing `www.domain.com` results in an `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.

Existing documentation is confusing and there's no clear way of configuring things end-to-end.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I've done to get domain.com and www.domain.com working you'll need this:

1. An A record for www
2. An A record @ 192.30.252.153
3. An A record @ 192.30.252.154
4. A CNAME aliasing www.domain.com to username.github.io. (note the trailing period)
5. The "CNAME" file in the GitHub Pages repo contains the text "domain.com"

I think the wildcard A record may be optional in your case but I'm not certain.

*Edit: Removed wildcard A record. @mheadroom pointed out that GitHub recommends against this entry because it would allow anyone to host a GitHub Pages site on one of your subdomains! https://help.github.com/articles/tips-for-configuring-a-cname-record-with-your-dns-provider/*

Comment: Thanks the only missing point was - The "CNAME" file in the GitHub Pages repo contains the text "domain.com"

Comment: Could you clarify what is meant for 1. An A record for www?

Comment: In the DNS settings for your domain, there will be a place where you can create "A Records". On that page, there will be text boxes for adding a "Host" and an "IP Address". An A Record for www simply means that you type "www" in the Host text box and leave the IP address blank and then add that record to your DNS settings.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Erik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30836844/624466), here's the slightly modified configuration that worked for me.

For my custom [(apex) domain](https://help.github.com/articles/about-supported-custom-domains/#apex-domains) `eyecatchup.rocks`, I set:

1. An `A record`: host `@`, destination `192.30.252.153`
2. An `A record`: host `@`, destination `192.30.252.154`
3. An `A record`: host `www`, destination `192.30.252.153`
4. An `A record`: host `www`, destination `192.30.252.154`
5. An `CNAME record`: host `www`, destination `eyecatchup.github.io`

[The "CNAME" file in the GitHub Pages repo](https://github.com/eyecatchup/eyecatchup.github.com/blob/master/CNAME) contains  `eyecatchup.rocks`.

[image]

With this set, both [eyecatchup.rocks](http://eyecatchup.rocks) as well as [www.eyecatchup.rocks](http://www.eyecatchup.rocks) point to my GitHub user page, originally available at [eyecatchup.github.io](http://eyecatchup.github.io).

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration at your DNS provider side is needed:

[image: Gihub pages configuration]